# Private Server In Client Network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I am currently deploying an Ubuntu server in my client network. Usually, my clients don't have strong networking configurations and it works fine. However, I have a new client with very strong requirements (which is better for him of course), but he needs me to list every IP and Ports that my server is communicating with.

The issue is that he does not want DNS and I am wondering how I could list IPs of Ubuntu Updates (reaching out to `*.canonical.com` ). Basically, the question is: what is the good practice to whitelist IPs when it may change. Is it impossible ? Or should I set up an intermediate server that would do the calls in between and whitelist this IP instead ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Image - https://postimg.cc/9rKCy065

Comment: What about `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: `/etc/hosts` would associate names to ips, but if the IP change for a given DNS, the file has to change

Comment: Correct, but based on your requirements this is quite good solution